# Problems setting up gmail on ipad

Tags: email, ipad

On my IPad I use a GMail app for my email.
However some applications seem to require sending via the built in Email client.
That's question #1 - why doesn't for example my camera app allow me to send pictures via gmail?
And question #2 is - the IPad default email client is not allowing me to create a new GMail account with my Gmail configuration in settings.
I  am doing the following in Settings:

- Mail, Contacts, Calendars
- Gmail
- Enter my Name, email address, Google password and description
  It gives me a dialog that says "The user name or password for "imap.gmail.com" is incorrect.

Why? This is the same info I use to configure my gmail client, and it works perfectly well.

What to do?
Signed
Cant move stuff off my IPad.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment the way iOS is set up is that if you want to send or share something it will only go through the Mail app.  It's a bit of a bummer, but that's how things are at the moment.  There are slight work arounds, so if you try to attach within an app it uses that app, but in all other cases by default it will always use Mail.

In regards to your Gmail not working, try referring to [this article](http://support.google.com/a/users/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=138740) to add your Gmail account to mail.  There are some things that have changed recently with Gmail on iOS devices.  It's not longer setup through exchange so it might not work as effectively as you would if you used the Gmail App.  Your mail will not be pushed automatically you will have manually open the Mail app and refresh to receive new mail.  Another bummer.

I hope this information helps!

Comment: No, sorry, I tried both sets of instructions (I have IOS 6 but I also tried other), and I still get a prompt asking me for the password.

Comment: Do you have two step verification turned on?

Comment: Yes, doesn't everybody? Is that an issue?

Comment: Could be, trying reseting captcha, captcha is a secuirity protocol that companies put in to place so that if a person enters a password too many times they have to enter some random text in to proove that they are not some computer trying to crack a password.   Go to this link log in and try again  https://www.google.com/accounts/UnlockCaptcha

Answer (score -1):

"imap.gmail.com" is the **wrong** setting.

try gmail.com

Comment: no, that did not help